# SSL Certificate not getting selected when adding iis binding

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I am trying to setup a https IIS Binding. I am using the following code.

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
var certList = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "*.mycert", true);
var certificate = certList[0];
var certificateHash = certificate.GetCertHash();
var certificateStoreName = store.Name;
ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
var httpSite = iisManager.Sites["mysite"];
var s = httpSite.Bindings;
string bind = "*:443:mysite.mysite.com";
var binding = httpSite.Bindings.Add(bind, certificateHash, certificateStoreName);
binding.Protocol = "https";

iisManager.CommitChanges();
```

The binding is created correctly with the exception of the certificate. If I go into IIS Manager and look at the bindings, the certificate dropdown is empty and I have to select the certificate manually from the list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See example 2.  You need to add the store to the collection : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store?force_isolation=true&view=net-5.0

Comment: You cannot use a certificate from `Root` but `My` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename?view=net-5.0

Comment: Any progress on that? I'm having the same problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by specifying a literal string instead of the StoreName.Root enum in the X509Store constructor. I keep my SSL certs in the "Web Hosting" folder. This will show the SSL cert as selected in IIS.

```
var store = new X509Store("WebHosting", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                    store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
                    X509Certificate2 certificate = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                        "*.mydomain.com", true)[0];
```